# error en VS al querer instalar extensión de salesforce

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar ese error al instalar salesforce en vs?

Comment: No todos pueden ver la imágenes: pon el error _como texto, con formato_. Además, ¿hiciste caso a lo que dice el mensaje? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: si hice loq ue decia el msj, bajé otra version de java y nada

Comment: Si colocás el mensaje como texto, será más fácil que otras personas con el mismo problema encuentren esta pregunta (y también atraerá más atención, ya que sí podrán ver el mensaje ;) ) `Set one using the salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home VS Code Setting`: ¿configuraste VS Code?